# Menu Jquery animated

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I want make a menu with Jquery like a drop downmenu. The only difference is that when I'm hovering in a li item (list item) I want to show up the submenus item and move up all the submenus and the li item... Ex

this is the menu before hover function:

```
 -------------------------
 Home     About    Company
 -------------------------
```

After hover on "About" li item :

```
----------------------------
      About
      subitem0
Home  subitem1  Company
      subitem2
----------------------------
```

Is this possible?

Comment: yes, very much possible. You just have to align them to the bottom of the parent element. Provide some code and I will provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpkBW/

Comment: P.S: This is not a simple drop-down menu because, as you can see, the "About" item is not inline with others items "home" and "company"...... So this is not a simple drop-down menu

Comment: @Pierluigi Ballatore: You'll notice that the container expands with the elements. They just need to be vertically aligned to the middle. Sorry, I forgot about this. I'll have a look for you when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

The Answer is Yes.